# Krakend can't get running services from consul (Docker)

Tags: docker-compose, microservices, consul, multiple-instances, krakend

I am using Consul as SD and while I am running multiple instances I want make gateway recognize them all to load balance.
In case of hardcoded host for Krakend config everything works fine

I was going step by step with this: https://www.krakend.io/docs/backends/service-discovery/

Sending

> dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 user-ms.service.consul SRV
> gives me response as well (on consul logs a also see that I've made a request)

But when I am making request via krakenD I am getting "no hosts available" and according to logs request wasn't send to consul

Here is a docker-compose file:

```
services:
  postgres:
     image: postgres:13
     restart: 'always'
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_DB=user-db
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
       - POSTGRES_USER=user
     ports:
       - "5432:5432"

 consul:
   image: consul:latest
   restart: 'always'

   ports:
     - '8500:8500'
     - '8600:8600/tcp'
     - '8600:8600/udp'

 krakend_gateway:
   image: devopsfaith/krakend:2
   volumes:
     - ./krakend.json:/krakend.json
   ports:
     - "1234:1234"
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8090:8090"

   command: [ "run", "-d", "-c", "/krakend.json" ]

 user-ms:
   build: user-ms/
   platform: linux/arm64
   restart: 'always'
   depends_on: [consul-server , krakend_gateway]
   ports:
     - '8082'
```

And pretty simple Krakend.json config file

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "timeout": "3000ms",
  "cache_ttl": "300s",
  "host" : "localhost:8080",
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/users",
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/api/v1/users",
          "sd" : "dns",
          "host" : [
            "user-ms.service.consul.srv"
          ],
          "disable_host_sanitize": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a lot of thing , but still get the same response , will be glad for any help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I am making request via krakenD I am getting "no hosts available" and according to logs request wasn't send to consul

The reason your request is failing is because Consul's DNS server listens on the non-standard port of 8600. Kraken does not appear to support configuring a custom DNS IP and non-standard port. It uses the underlying host's configured nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` resolve SRV requests, and expects these IPs to be reachable over port 53.

The following is a Docker compose file that includes the following changes to allow Kraken to resolve DNS against Consul.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
---
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: 'always'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=user-db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - vpcbr

  consul:
    image: consul:latest
    restart: 'always'
    environment:
      CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG: |
        {
          "recursors": [
            "8.8.8.8",
            "8.8.4.4"
          ],
          "dns_config": {
            "recursor_strategy": "random"
          },
          "ports": {
            "dns": 53
          },
          "services": [
            {
              "name": "user-ms",
              "address": "192.0.2.20",
              "port": 8082
            }
          ]
        }
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 192.0.2.10
    ports:
      - '8500:8500'
      - '8600:53/tcp'
      - '8600:53/udp'

  krakend_gateway:
    image: devopsfaith/krakend:2
    command: [ "run", "-d", "-c", "/krakend.json" ]
    dns: 192.0.2.10
    volumes:
      - ./krakend.json:/krakend.json
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8090:8090"
    networks:
      - vpcbr

  user-ms:
    build: user-ms/
    platform: linux/arm64
    restart: 'always'
    depends_on: [consul, krakend_gateway]
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 192.0.2.20
    ports:
      - '8082'

networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.0.2.0/24
```

#### Docker compose changes

1. The containers have been deployed onto a separate private network, `vpcbr`, with the IP range of 192.0.2.0/24. This is so that a static IP can be assigned to the Consul container.
2. The `consul` container has been issued a static IP of 192.0.2.10 from the `vpcbr` network.
3. The remaining containers have been configured to obtain a dynamic IP from `vpcbr`.
4. The `krakend_gateway` container has been configured to use `192.0.2.10` (Consul) for upstream DNS resolution.

#### Consul changes

1. Consul has been configured with a static registration for the `user-ms` service. Alternatively, you can use a program like [Registrator](https://gliderlabs.github.io/registrator/latest/) to dynamically register containers from Docker into Consul.
2. Consul has been updated to listen on port 53 instead of 8600.
3. Consul has also been configured with a set of upstream DNS recursors so that it can resolve DNS queries for non `.consul` TLDs.

#### Kraken changes

1. The example DNS hostname in Kraken's documentation is incorrect for integrating with Consul. The `.srv` suffix should be removed as Consul only handles queries for records under the `.consul` top-level domain.

```json
{
  "version": 3,
  "timeout": "3000ms",
  "cache_ttl": "300s",
  "host": "localhost:8080",
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/users",
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/api/v1/users",
          "sd": "dns",
          "host": [
            "user-ms.service.consul"
          ],
          "disable_host_sanitize": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

With this configuration, I can see that Kraken successfully resolves the `user-ms.service.consul` domain against Consul DNS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
This one worked for me , at least Krakend finally able to make a request to consul. But I am getting something weird in logs as a requested data: consul: agent.dns: request served from client: name=c000020a.addr.dc1.consul. type=A class=IN latency=1.004833ms client=192.0.2.3:52409 client_network=udp Krakend: Get "c000020a.addr.dc1.consul.:8082/api/v1/users": dial tcp 192.0.2.10:8082: connect: connection refused And time by time I see this log from consul agent.dns: request served from client: name=user-ms.service.consul. type=SRV –

Comment: I'm glad this is mostly working for you. Thanks for the feedback. I realized that I missed one critical detail; the way the service is registered to Consul will cause Consul to return the IP of the Consul server itself, not the IP of the container where your application is running. I'll update the example docker compose file to correct this. Note that this would not be a problem if you used Registrator to register the services, as it would register them with the correct IP of the app container.

Comment: Thanks again , really helped me. Will try with Registrator  (seems like this is what I need) a bit later , god bless you , I was sitting with this for 1 week)